# remove border in UICollectionView when cells loaded from xib

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, border, xib

I have a collectionView and my cells are loaded from a xib.

I'm trying to remove the border (I want only shadow) with the following lines:

```
cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0 //I also tried with 0.0
cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

But it doesn't seems to be working.

I try put these lines in the next function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

And even in the function `awakeFromNib` in the cell class.

Any idea how can I remove the border ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are trying is for `borderWidth` and border color.

Use below lines for shadow and remove the above code.

```
cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = false
cell.contentView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
cell.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
cell.contentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
cell.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 1

cell.contentView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
cell.contentView.layer.shouldRasterize = true

cell.contentView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```

Comment: Thanks! the issue was the masksToBounds flag.